# How can I create a snapshot from the video via libvlcjni?

Tags: java, android, vlc, libvlc

Before, I used `TextureView` as video container. I could take a snapshot via `getBitmap()`.
But I'm updated the VLCMobileKit, and now I using this code:

```
        <org.videolan.libvlc.util.VLCVideoLayout
        android:id="@+id/vlc_surfaceView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
```

I tried to take a snapshot via `buildDrawingCache()` but is always return with an empty image.

```
                    videoLayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                    videoLayout.buildDrawingCache();
                    Bitmap bitmap = videoLayout.getDrawingCache();
```

I tried to take a screenshot from the full of activity. I saw the video layout is transparent on the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not get the snapshot directly. You have to use a SurfaceView instead of VLCVideoLayout to get the current frame.

PixelCopy class can convert the SurfaceView frame to Bitmap. So you have to replace your VLCVideoLayout with a SurfaceView. Attach this surface view to your MediaPlayer before playing the media.

```
mMediaPlayer.vlcVout.setVideoView(surfaceView)
mMediaPlayer.vlcVout.attachViews()
```

Now use call the below function to get the current video snapshot bitmap.

```
fun usePixelCopy(videoView: SurfaceView, callback: (Bitmap?) -> Unit) {
    val bitmap: Bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
            videoView.width,
            videoView.height,
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
    )
    try {
        val handlerThread = HandlerThread("PixelCopier")
        handlerThread.start()
        PixelCopy.request(
                videoView, bitmap,
                { copyResult ->
                    if (copyResult == PixelCopy.SUCCESS) {
                        callback(bitmap)
                    }
                    handlerThread.quitSafely()
                },
                Handler(handlerThread.looper)
        )
    } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
        callback(null)
        e.printStackTrace()
        showMessage(R.string.error)
    }
}
```

Note: Code is in Kotlin and works only in Android N and above. I'm using it in my VideoPlayer app.